# Schema.org for multiple areas served and local business

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

I have a client who operates locally but also sells his services (in the managed technology niche) across North America. I have created these two scripts for his website and was wondering if you guys could help. This is the first time I have done schema.org of this nature.

I am hoping to put this one on the services page (we do not have local pages for each service area).

```html
<script type='application/ld+json'>
 {
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "Service",
    "areaServed": ["Canada", "United States"],
    "produces": "Managed IT"
}
</script>
```

Also, here is the local business schema I created. What do you think? I am pretty sure it is correct, but will it mess with my services page schema if I place it in the footer? Am I sending too many signals?

```html
 <script type='application/ld+json'> 
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "LocalBusiness",
  "name": "Client",
  "url": "https://client.com/",
  "logo": "https://client.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/header-
logo.png",
  "image": "https://client.com/wp-
content/uploads/2016/11/scout2016_small.jpg",
  "description": "Discover what works and what needs updating to 
streamline your IT services. Get your 
custom Scout Tech Guides managed services free tech audit today!",
   "address": {
    "@type": "PostalAddress",
    "streetAddress": "109-9440 202 St",
    "addressLocality": "Langley",
    "addressRegion": "British Columbia",
    "postalCode": "V1M4A6",
    "addressCountry": "Canada"
      },
      "geo": {
    "@type": "GeoCoordinates",
    "latitude": "49.174440",
    "longitude": "-122.664108"
  },
      "openingHours": "Mo, Tu, We, Th, Fr 09:00-17:00",
      "contactPoint": {
        "@type": "ContactPoint",
        "contactType": "Customer Service",
        "telephone": "+1 (866)-546-5283"
     }
    }
     </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With structured data, there are never "too many signals" as long as these signals are correct and don’t deceive.

You can combine the two `script` elements into one. This offers the advantage to easily link the two items together, so you can say: this `Service` is provided by this `LocalBusiness`.

On the service page, you could have:

```json
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "LocalBusiness",
  "name": "The business",
  "@reverse": { "provider": 
    {
      "@type": "Service",
      "name": "The service"
    }
  }
}
```

(I’m making use of `@reverse` because Schema.org doesn’t define an inverse property for `provider`. Instead of using `@reverse`, you could as well make the `Service` the top-level item and use `provider` to reference the `LocalBusiness` item.)